# Share info Between Discord.py Commands

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord Bot that will kick and ban users, then log the information to a #mod-log channel automatically. This is working fine as I have specified the #mod-log channel ID for my testing server. But if my bot is in a different server, I want the moderators of that server to set their own #mod-log channel. I've written the following command:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def setmodlog(self,ctx,mlog:discord.Channel):
    """Sets mod-log channel"""
    await self.bot.say("Mod Log channel set")
```

I want that "mlog" variable to carry over to my kick/ban commands so it will log to the channel specified by the moderator. However, that is not working. The "mlog" variable doesn't carry over. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a dictionary of server IDs to channel IDs.  Update that dictionary when `setmodlog` is called and check it for your other commands

```
modlog = {}

async def on_ready(self):
    global modlog
    try:
        with open('modlog.json') as f:
            modlog = json.load(f)
    except:
        modlog = {}

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def setmodlog(self,ctx,mlog:discord.Channel):
    """Sets mod-log channel"""
    modlog[ctx.message.server.id] = mlog.id
    await self.bot.say("Mod Log channel set")
    with open('modlog.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(modlog, f)

@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    server = ctx.message.server
    author = ctx.message.author
    message = "{} kicked {}".format(author.name, member.name)
    await bot.kick(member)
    channel = modlog[server.id]
    await bot.send_message(server.get_channel(channel), message)
```

Comment: @TheLarkShark Note that this mapping will disappear if your bot stops running.  You may want to save it to a file, that you can load in you `on_ready` event.

Comment: How would I do that? How would the bot know which channels to assign to which servers?

Comment: @TheLarkShark Because an administrator invoked `!setmodlog #somechannel`.  The dictionary is a mapping between servers and their log channels. I will add loading/saving to this example.